# How to create a graphical application where the list of active processes is displayed in a list

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

So I have this school assignment that goes like this:

Create a graphical application where the list of active processes in the system is displayed in a list box. For the selected process from the list, the following information will be specified:

1. The appropriate PID
2. The name of the executable file on which the process was launched

I've made this, which show me if task manager is opened and if its opened it displays memory address:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD ProcessID;

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, ("Task Manager"));

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &ProcessID);

    if (hwnd) {
        cout << ProcessID << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Windows Not Found" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Can you guys help me by pointing in a direction or give some information to fulfill my asignment? Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need the process id of a maybe open task manager but a list of processes running on the system and a window containing a listbox to display it.

Comment: Some info: [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/process-enumeration)
Also, don't think you've failed because you can't display all information about all processes. Some you don't have permissions to examine. You can run your final program as administrator to get some more info, but some will be really hard to find out.

Comment: Is going with WIndows API to create the GUI a requirement? If it is not, I'd urge you not to go down this route and use a framework.

Comment: Otoh, there are some pretty short and simple examples on MSDN for doing this. The
[Enumerating All Processes example](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) could be used as a base.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use psapi. And it isn't toooo hard:

```
#include <cstddef>  // std::size_t
#include <vector>   // std::vector<>
#include <string>   // std::wstring
#include <sstream>  // std::wostringstream

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>  // CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(), Process32FirstW(),
                       // Process32NextW(),
#include <commctrl.h>  // InitCommonControlsEx(), ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES, WC_LISTVIEWW
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")  // tell Linker to link against the
                                      // Windows Common Controls Library

struct process_data_t {  // datastructure to represent a process
    std::wstring pid;    // number as string for convenience
    std::wstring name;   // the name of the executable
};

// function to get the current processes running on the system
void update_process_data(std::vector<process_data_t> &process_data)
{
                   // take a snapshot of the running processes
    auto snapshot{ CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0) };

    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {  // validate the result
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() failed :(", L"Error:", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return;
    }

    // Process32FirstW() and Process32NextW() will fill a structure of type
    PROCESSENTRY32W pe{ sizeof pe };       // with info about one process at 
    if (!Process32FirstW(snapshot, &pe)) { // a time from the snapshot
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Process32FirstW() failed :(", L"Error:", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        CloseHandle(snapshot);
        return;
    }

    BOOL result{ true };   // result of Process32NextW()
    process_data.clear();  // discard the old data

    for (std::size_t i{}; result; result = Process32NextW(snapshot, &pe), ++i) {
        if (i + 1 > process_data.capacity())  // if we come close to the vectors
            process_data.reserve(process_data.capacity() + 100); // capacity, increase it

        std::wostringstream woss;  // a stream to convert the process-id
        woss << pe.th32ProcessID;  // to a std::wstring

        // add the data to our vector:
        process_data.push_back({ woss.str(), pe.szExeFile });
    }

    // don't forget to close the handle opened by CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()
    CloseHandle(snapshot);  // better solution: use a `std::unique_ptr<>` with
};                          // a custom deleter. Sorry, was to lazy to do so.

// Window procedure that will get called when our application receives messages
LRESULT APIENTRY window_proc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    static HWND list_view;  // a handle to the listview we'll create in WM_CREATE
    static std::vector<process_data_t> process_data;  // data about processes
                                                      // to display in the
                                                      // listview

    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE:  // create child-windows when the parent gets created:
        {
            CREATESTRUCTW *create_struct{ reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lparam) };
            list_view = CreateWindowW(WC_LISTVIEWW, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT | LVS_OWNERDATA,
                                      5, 5, create_struct->cx - 10, create_struct->cy - 10,
                                      window, (HMENU)100, create_struct->hInstance, nullptr);
            if (!list_view)  // abort window creation if
                return -1;   // creation of the listview child failed

            LVCOLUMNW columns[2];  // to add 2 columns to our listview
            columns[0].mask = columns[1].mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
            columns[0].pszText = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"PID");
            columns[0].cx = 200;  // width of the column
            columns[1].pszText = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"Name");
            columns[1].cx = 800;  // dito
            for (std::size_t i{}; i < std::size(columns); ++i) {
                // insert the column to the listview:
                if (SendMessageW(list_view, LVM_INSERTCOLUMN, i, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&columns[i])) == -1)
                    return -1;
            }

            update_process_data(process_data);  // populate our process data

            // tell the listview how many items to display:
            SendMessageW(list_view, LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, process_data.size(), LVSICF_NOSCROLL);

            // have Windows send us a message (WM_TIMER) every 250 ms
            SetTimer(window, 0, 250, nullptr);

            return 0;  // all went well.
        }

        case WM_TIMER:  // message we receive every 250 ms to update
            update_process_data(process_data);  // the process data

            // and inform the listview about changes in the item count
            SendMessageW(list_view, LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, process_data.size(), LVSICF_NOSCROLL);
            return 0;

        case WM_NOTIFY:  // we will be notified when the listview wants us
                         // to provide data to display
            if (reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(lparam)->code == LVN_GETDISPINFO) {
                NMLVDISPINFO *dispinfo{ reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(lparam) };
                if (dispinfo->item.iSubItem) {  // if the listview wants subitem
                                                // at index dispinfo->item.iItem
                    dispinfo->item.pszText = const_cast<wchar_t*>(process_data[dispinfo->item.iItem].name.c_str());  // give it the process' name
                }
                else {
                    dispinfo->item.pszText = const_cast<wchar_t*>(process_data[dispinfo->item.iItem].pid.c_str());   // give it the pid
                }
                return TRUE;
            }
            return 0;

        case WM_SIZE:
            // resize our child-window along with its parent:
            MoveWindow(list_view, 5, 5, LOWORD(lparam) - 10, HIWORD(lparam) - 10, TRUE);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, char*, int show_state)
{
    // initialize the Windows Common Controls library to use a listview
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex{ sizeof iccex, ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES };
    if (!InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex)) {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Initializing common windows controls library failed :(", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    // prepare the window class for our window:
    WNDCLASSW wc{};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = window_proc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Poor Mans TaskMan Window Class";
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_PARENTDC;

    // register the window class and check for possible error:
    ATOM window_class{ RegisterClass(&wc) };
    if (!window_class) {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Registering window class failed :(", L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    // create a window of our now registered window class and handle possible error:
    HWND window{ CreateWindowW(reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(window_class), L"Poor Mans TaskMan", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                               CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, instance,
                               nullptr)
    };
    if (!window) {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Creating window failed :(", L"Error:", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return 0;
    }

    // update and show the window:
    UpdateWindow(window);
    ShowWindow(window, show_state);

    // message-pump:
    MSG msg;
    BOOL result;
    while (result = GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        if (result == -1)
            return msg.wParam;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me a bit what's going on in there? I kinda lost myself a bit

Comment: @Alexandra I'll add comments as soon as I have time.

Comment: @Alexandra Done. If you have further questions feel free to ask away.

Comment: Don't think we should be doing homework projects in this way. This question should be closed rather than answered.